# Clustering and replication in ArangoDB

Tags: cluster-computing, replication, arangodb

Hi since I'm fairly new to ArangoDB I have a couple of question regarding clustering and replications. It seems that the documentation is not really clear on those topics:

1. What is the purpose of having a cluster in ArangoDB since the
   replication is not enabled but default and thus the failover would
   not make any sense there. Is the idea to have a shared data store
   all instances in the cluster should have access to?
2. Since the replication model can be either sync or async what about
   the replication factor on a collection. So the replication needs to
   configured on each database individually, and the idea to set the
   replication factor on the collection level? My understanding is that
   changing the replication factor on the collection level would make
   the replication to be sync, but what if the database replication is
   in an async mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Really? https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/cluster. The idea is that you may gain both performance through distributing work load on coordinators, distributing your huge database over multiple db servers and gain fail-safety and resilience towards hardware failures and networking issues. You may even go on to replicated entire clusters in different data centers.
2. The replication factor is not defined over the database but on the collection level. When you deploy a collection in a clustered database you define replication factor and number of shards as optional parameters. All system collections are deployed with replication factor 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Yes I did see the that page, but be honest what exactly are they outlining there other that some generic cluster description. The get a better performance from a cluster the data will need to be distributed as well. So if the main point in sharding the data across the cluster, then this will need to be mentioned. However failover in this case will not do you any good, unless the data is replicated.

Comment: I guess you did not get my other question. I understand that the replication factor is set on a collection level. I was asking what if I set my database to be replicated asynchronously and set the replication factor to 2 or 3. What happens  then?

Comment: There is not asynchronous replication in the cluster since version 3.0.

Comment: This is the functionality of what a "generic" database cluster gives you. Sharding + replication. I am one of the cluster's core programmers. Don't know really how to elaborate on that. The sharding allows one to distribute huge data over many servers with the related complexity disguised from the user. While the synchronous replication part takes care of the safety aspect.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you for you response. I was not aware that an asynchronous replication is not supported on a cluster any more. So basically I would only need to set the replication factor on a collection, that's it right? Just out of curiosity, why it has been decided on a replication setting on a collection level and not on a database level as well?

Comment: For the highest possible flexibility. This would leave the creation of all collections in a database and their respective replication factors to the discretion of the application developer. I would admit that I have no compelling case for different replication factors > 1. But imagine that you have some volatile stuff in the database like live user sessions. You might not care for replication with those volatile data.

Comment: true, I agree there